# Rails 4 how to pass dynamic params to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-for

I have this form in my view:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :update_quantity}, :params => [:ids_to_update]) do %>
<% @id_array = [] %>
<% @db_lines.each do |line| %>
<% @id_array << line['id'] %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= image_tag "#{line['preview_url']}&maxSize=135" %></td>
      <td><%= line['ProductCode'] %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag("updated_quantity#{line['id']}", "#{line['Quantity']}") %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(line['UnitPrice']) %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(line['Quantity'] * line['UnitPrice']) %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :ids_to_update, @id_array.join(',') %>
    <%= submit_tag("Update Quantity", :class => 'tiny button raidus') %>
    </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

In the text_field_tag i'm setting each name to be updated_quantityx where x is the ID of the record. How do I pass each one of those into the params section of the form_tag when I don't know what the ID will be and how many will be there? The records are coming from my order_line model and this page is a separate controller for the shopping cart..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `params` section in the `form_tag`.
Params will be automatically generated by `_tags` inside the form.

The text_field_tag values will be passed to the controller as `params[:updated_quantity#1]`, `params[:updated_quantity#2]` and so on.